# C++ Regex Sub Matches not appearing

Tags: c++, regex

I am making a regular expression to modify the 2nd and 3rd parameters in a function. I am using the regex.h library that comes with most linux distributions. I can't seem to get the submatches to appear in the code below.

Code:

```
       string s ("tweenArray.push(addNewPoint(posTween, 1 , 2, .3, scale, brushWidth));");
       regex e ("(tweenArray.push\\(addNewPoint\\(posTween,)\s*(.+?),\s*(.+?),");   // matches words beginning by "sub"
       smatch m;

       regex_match ( s, m, e );
       cout << "match " << 0 << " (" << m[0] << ")" << endl;
       cout << "match " << 1 << " (" << m[1] << ")" << endl;
       cout << "match " << 2 << " (" << m[2] << ")" << endl;
       cout << "match " << 3 << " (" << m[3] << ")" << endl;
       cout << regex_replace (s,e,"$1 0, 0");
```

Output:

```
       match 0 ()
       match 1 ()
       match 2 ()
       match 3 ()
       tweenArray.push(addNewPoint(posTween,  0 , 0,  .3 scale, brushWidth));
```

THe replace works perfectly, which tells me that the regular expression is correct. However, the sub matches aren't being displayed. Why wont the sub matches display?

Comment: Your matching groups for matching the arguments in `addNewPoint` were only matching the first two arguments. You may try this regex `(tweenArray\\.push\\(addNewPoint\\(posTween,)\\s*?((.+?\\s*?),)+\\s*?(.+?)+\\)\\);`

Comment: I'm sorry, i should have been more specific, I only want to capture the second and third argument of the addNewPoint Function. So I want to extrace the "1" and "2".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think regex_match requires the whole string to match.

```
Important
Note that the result is true only if the expression matches the whole of 
the input sequence. If you want to search for an expression somewhere 
within the sequence then use regex_search. If you want to match a prefix of 
the character string then use regex_search with the flag match_continuous set.
```

So, maybe this would work

`".*?tweenArray.push\\(addNewPoint\\(posTween,\\s*(.+?),\\s*(.+?),.*"`

```
 .*? 
 tweenArray . push\(addNewPoint\(posTween, 
 \s* 
 ( .+? )                       # (1)
 , \s* 
 ( .+? )                       # (2)
 ,
 .*
```

Output:

```
 **  Grp 0 -  ( pos 0 , len 69 ) 
tweenArray.push(addNewPoint(posTween, 1 , 2, .3, scale, brushWidth));  
 **  Grp 1 -  ( pos 38 , len 2 ) 
1   
 **  Grp 2 -  ( pos 42 , len 1 ) 
2
```